# refresh_ce meaning and origin

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

does anybody know meaning and origin of http url parameter named "**refresh_ce**"? This character typically appears immediately after question mark character. I think it's generated by meta refresh (or javascript) in order to let server know "it'not the first access" to that page.
who created this name? Is it a standard de-facto?
I couldn't find any important info googling this term.

If it's something ancient, is it still important (for legacy browsers/systems)?

Thank you.

Comment: Most of the URLs that are listed when I google "refresh_ce" appear to be Italian.

Comment: It's not something I've encountered, but I was curious so I did a little googling. I think your suggestion is correct - the site is refreshing the page, and adding a flag to say "we already refreshed, so don't refresh again". Why they are refreshing in the first place, who knows, but judging from this forum post http://userscripts.org/topics/9324 it must be annoying. You'll find a code snippet there too. I would guess the technique and variable name is not widespread. As martin noted it seems to only be used on a couple of Italian sites - perhaps sites created by the same developer?

Comment: thanks very much guys for search restriction :-) I didn't know it was only about few countries (perhaps only Italian sites). I suspect it has something to do with traffic analysis products. Actually, the "refresh_ce" seems to be quite common on many large Italian portals...

Comment: I'm starting to have this problem! Many pages have this parameter and they autorefresh in 2 seconds.. continuously!  Only with chrome

Answer (score 4):

At least in Italy, this parameter is linked with the standards of the local publishing/advertising market. These standard state that pages are allowed to refresh every 5 minutes (or more). Such refreshes are used to bump up page and ad impressions and to show a new set of ads to users. The refresh_ce parameter is used to identify refreshed page impressions, which are excluded from some analyses and counts.

Another similar parameter is refresh_ce-awe, which marks the impressions that are generated when only some contents (not the whole page) is refreshed. This usually happens when the users browse photo galleries.

Comment: Most annoying things are often bound to advertising. And this page refresh is one of the ugliest things I've ever seen in internet.

Comment: It is certainly annoying on contents pages (e.g. articles), especially when it's coupled with invasive advertising (e.g. video overlays). I would say it's much less noticeable on home pages with refresh times of at least 5 minutes (most people will already be on another tab or not even in front of the computer any more).

Comment: @roccobarbi actually if you scroll the homepage of the most popular newspaper in Italy and you want to read most of the titles you won't get to the bottom, because it will refresh earlier

Comment: @mcont that is true now, since most large website embraced the concept of an infinite scroll with lazy loading of the ad slots. It wasn't always true when the question was asked and when I answered it. Even with infinite scrolling, many news websites in Italy still reload the whole page after about 5 minutes on home pages (please note that I'm using a very broad definition of "news sites" that includes most large publishers and periodicals).

Comment: I don't see any infinite scrolling actually. If you open Repubblica or Corriere the homepages are very long from the beginning (according to the scrollbars), and you can scroll to the bottom to see that the page has an end. Where it's hard to get though